# Upgrading python3.5

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dependencies

Whatever I try to install for upgrading my Python3.5 I get the following error:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

When I run the following command: sudo apt --fix-broken install
it says

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01/./libcublas-dev_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Which python version do you need to use? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1320451/edit) your question accordingly

Comment: Right now I am trying Python3.6 or python3.7 but nothing is installing in my Ubuntu16

Comment: See my answer for a possible method of upgrading. What did you try, which gave these errors?

Comment: Everything was working absolutely fine when I tried to implement a project from Github. It asked for upgraded Python. I started trying to upgrade my Python3.5 but could not upgrade anything as the system is not allowing me to install anything.

Comment: First we need to fix this before installing a later version of Python. Does it help to remove that `libcublas` package? `sudo apt-get remove libcublas-dev` It seems that you (unintentionally) messed up your system while trying to configure something related to CUDA

Comment: Package 'libcublas-dev' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-libraries-dev-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-samples-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-visual-tools-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Then try `sudo apt-get remove cuda-libraries-dev  cuda-samples-10-2 cuda-visual-tools-10-2`. If it does not work, you can ask a new question about this specific error (which seems to have nothing to do with python), and then get back to installing python once that issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can install other versions of Python alongside python3.5, instead of replacing it.

To do that, you can add the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to your system.

Open a terminal and enter the commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Once done, you can install the version of python you need, with the command

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

You can replace the 3.7 with something else, the PPA supports all Python3 versions, from `python3.1` - `python3.10`.

Once installed, to run python3.7, open a terminal, and enter the command `python3.7` (or any other `python3.x`).

**Warning**: **Do not** remove `python3.5` after installing `python3.x`. Removing `python3.5` may break your system, and you may have to reinstall Ubuntu to fix that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. 

Actually whatever I am trying to install it says: 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution

Comment: I didn't even try to uninstall Python3.5. 
I even tried to install Python3.8 in a virtual environment. But nothing is working except sudo apt-get update.